# Tableau Calculation to dynamic rolling distinct count per month

Tags: tableau-desktop

I was asked to convert my previous Excel and `PowerBI` dashboards to Tableau and I encountered the problem where I need to show base on the [invoice date], the distinct count of [supplier code] in each month, together with the distinct count of [supplier code] over previous 13 month from the current month. I have made a brief example as below:

My dataset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVg8w.png)

This is all of the invoices for each supplier code over 5 year period (1/jan/2019 - 31/dec/2023), as you can see, each day could have multiple [supplier code].

My goal: (based on Year-Month level)

[image]

This will be an area chart, between the distinct count of [supplier code] for that month, and the distinct count of [supplier code] for a rolling 13 months, i.e.:

1. there will be no value for the period from Jan 2019 to Jan 2020, as these periods don't have 13 months of data;
2. the first 13-months distinct count point will be at Feb 2020, all the way to Dec 2023.

The current distinct count is easy, it goes with whatever the dimension I drag to the row/column, just something as 'COUNTD([Supplier Code])'. The pain is for the rolling 13 months, I have no idea how Tableau takes the filter into its calculation.

I would like to know how do I give Tableau the dynamical date range (i.e. 13months previous from each current month).

I also confused about the 'FIXED' method, I got something like:

```
{FIXED [Supplier Code],[Invoice Date]:
MIN(IF [Invoice Date] = {EXCLUDE [Invoice Date] : MIN([Invoice Date])}
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
)}
```

when I dragged this to the table, it generates the new distinct count of [supplier code] of the current month, compare to all months before current month. well this is my best approach at the moment, as if I use another calculation of 'RUNNING_SUM(SUM())' on the above code, it gets the correct result for 'Feb 2020', as it is the first distinct point of the rolling 13 months. And then it just adds whatever the new distinct count of [supplier code] all the way to the last month of my dataset.

Looking forward to different approaches here~

Comment: self-added comment to make the thread alive.

Comment: As a note when asking questions on SO, limit your questions to a single question, it makes searching for answers easier for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated field to grab the last 13 months of your invoice date and base it off the TODAY() date function to make it dynamic.

Make a calculation and name it `[Rolling Invoice Date]`:

```
IF [Invoice Date] >= DATEADD('month', -13, TODAY()) AND [Invoice Date] <= TODAY() THEN [Invoice Date] END
```

This checks if the invoice date is inside a date range of 13 months prior to today or up to today.

To help clarify:
`FIXED` calculations pin or "fix" the level of detail for the calculation to whatever level of the field you put before the colon in that calculation. [Read more on it here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm#FIXED).

Comment: Hi MUFF., thanks so much, just as my intension is to have a dynamic way to calculate the running sum of distinct count over each 13-month period, would you please give me another approach on this? Much appreciated.

Comment: I edited my answer so you may use `[Rolling Invoice Date]` as a date filter. Drag it to your filter pane and set it to true. Drag `[Invoice Date]` to columns and `[Amount]` to rows, choose "Area" in the marks pane and right click `[amount]` add a table calculation for running total and calculate it as 'across'. [See more on table calculations here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations_definebasic_runningtotal.htm#running-total-calculation)

Comment: Hi MUFF, first of all, thanks for your efforts here. But I am trying to have the running distinct count on [supplier code], not the sum of [amount]. And 'TODAY()' is just a static value, it won't give the last 13 months of 'distinct count' for each year-month within my dataset, right?

Comment: Apologies switch `[amount]` for `COUNTD([supplier code])` the logic will work. The function TODAY() gets todays date from tableau, from here, use the function "DATEADD" with it,  and you can subtract 13 months from today, giving you the ***Rolling*** 13 month window for your `[invoice date]`

Comment: If you add that calculation to your filter pane, it will filter all the dates in your worksheet to a 13 month window.  It is a more custom version of [relative date filters.](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/qs_relative_dates.htm)

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so, feel free to accept the answer so other may easily find if they run into the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: Hi MUFF, sorry about not being responsive. I've solved the issue with the joint of a date-table, so Tableau then can use that table as a measure for the data table. I have not tried your method as it looks like it is not the 'dynamic way' I would like to achieve.

Comment: Glad it was solved. Look into the TODAY() function on Tableau, it is dynamic.